# Javascript "is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to run a simple cheerio scraping script here:

```
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      var scoresTable = $('.grey').html();
      var scoresTableTbody = scoresTable('tbody');
      console.log(scoresTableTbody);
```

But the return is:

`scoresTable is not a function`

I also tried changing `var scoresTable = $('.grey').html();` into `var scoresTable = $('.grey');`, but same error.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scoresTable` is an string, not a function.

Assuming `grey` is a class assigned to a table try, to get the object reference to that element then use [.find()](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#findselector) get the tbody like

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
var scoresTable = $('.grey');
var scoresTableTbody = scoresTable.find('tbody');
console.log(scoresTableTbody);
```